# C++ program not entering a for loop using vector

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, cin

I was practicing with vector, I wanted to push an element using `push_back();` using a for loop, but the program doesn't even enter the for loop, help!!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "check ";
    int val;
    vector<char> vec;
    cout << "check " << endl << "Its in the game";
    //those two "check" were to confirm if the program is even running and is it a 
    problem while declaring the vector 

    for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++){
      
      cout << "enter element for vector" << endl;
      cin >> val;
      vec.push_back(val);
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Your vector is empty...

Comment: The default size of a vector is zero. You never initialized it. Try `vector<char> vec = {'a', 'b', 'c'};`

Comment: @GuyMarino even if the vector's initialized to something, the loop will go on infinitely. I'm not sure what exactly the intention of OP's program is.

Comment: You need to replace `i < vec.size()` with something else perhaps some value you ask the user.

Comment: Maybe you meant to loop a certain number of times, e.g. `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)` instead of `for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)`? It doesn't make sense to add an element to the vector for every element in the vector.

Comment: @GuyMarino -- the code initialized the vector by its default constructor.

Comment: @JoelRummel you're right. He really should do `vec.reserve(n)`, and then `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)` where `n` is some constant.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)` -- Now I'm wondering if this is a cut/copy-and-paste error.  The loop is obviously wrong there, but would be correct in some other scenario.

Answer (score 5):

Your vector is empty. The for loop starts at zero, which is not less than zero, so the for loop never runs.

Comment: And even if it was not initially empty, every iteration increases the size of the vector by 1, so the loop will be an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector is literally empty, which means `vec.size()` is 0.So It will never enter the loop. If you know what your vector size is gonna be, you should define it as

```
std::vector<int> vec(vec_size);
for(int i=0;i<vec_size;++i)
{
    //whatever.....
}
```

Or you could have used a `while` loop.

```
while(std::cin>>val)
{
    //do your thing....
}
```